# Recover data from an ''unpartitioned'' hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I'm trying to recover data from a hdd for a friend from work. He was using it on an old win98 PC (so I guess it was a FAT 16 filesystem). When he installed the drive on a new PC his Windows XP can't recognize the filesystem and give an error message saying that the drive is unformatted.

I tried to mount the hdd under linux but no partitions appear to be associated with the drive (I have only /dev/sdb associated with that drive and no /dev/sdb1 or sdb2 etc).

I've found many articles on the web on how to recover partitions (with scripts like dd and ddrescue) but how do I make it when I have no partitions and the system say my drive is unpartioned?

Is it possible to create a new partition without loosing the data?

Comment: it could also have been a FAT32 filesystem.  depending on circumstances it may have used a drive overlay (read: special driver) to get around BIOS/controller size limitations... this might make it difficult to identify old partitions on systems without this driver.

Comment: if possible, identify the drive (manufacturer & model) and motherboard of the old system, pls.

Comment: Did you ever get this problem solved?

Answer (score 4):

you might want to give [photorec and testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) a run - i've seen them recover data and entire file systems under similar circumstances

Comment: +1 for testdisk, it should be able to recover the whole partition table or the single files on the drive.